# Why is my SOAP call from ASP.net Core 2.2 returning a null result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap, wsdl

I'm having an issue where some SOAP calls are returning null objects in ASP.netCore 2.2.  I appreciate any help that anyone can give, I'm not getting much support from the vendor and I know this may be a lot to ask.

I'm able to make some calls successfully and get expected results.  Other calls are received by the API successfully (for example I can post data to the API), and return results in SOAP UI, but in my ASP.net application the return objects are null.  I've confirmed that the data I'm sending works.  The result does contain the expected model types, but the contents of the models are null.

The call that works returns a simple model, the call that doesn't work has a more complicated return type.  I suspect that is the important difference, but I can't see anywhere to debug how things go wrong.  The result process does hit the constructor for the return object, but it hits the empty constructor, not the one that I'd expect to return the value.  I don't know if that's an issue or not, or how to troubleshoot it.  I also have my doubts about the namespace in use on the WSDL code. I can't resolve that address, so it it's used for deserialization it seems like that would be an issue.  Do I need to add that to my project somehow?

The code for the API calls is generated by a WSDL.  I'm new to SOAP APIs and WSDLs, so this has been tough so far.  There's unfortunately a lot happening here that I don't understand but I hope i'm close since I can get some calls to work.  Much of appears to be 'black-box' as far as I'm concerned.  I'm not sure where else to turn.

Here is the call that works successfully:

My call that works:

```
var task = await cardManagementEPClient.getCardAsync(EFSConnection.ClientID, testCardNumber);
```

My call that returns a null result:

```
var task = await cardManagementEPClient.getPayrollCashHistoryAsync(EFSConnection.ClientID, cardNumber, beginDate, DateTime.Now);
```

The WSDL interface for the calls:

```
namespace Project.EFS.Interfaces
{    
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://com.tch.cards.service", ConfigurationName = "CardManagementEP")]
    public interface ICardManagementEP
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults = true)]
        [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name = "result")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSCard> getCardAsync(string clientId, string cardNumber);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults = true)]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<getPayrollCashHistoryResponse> getPayrollCashHistoryAsync(getPayrollCashHistoryRequest request);
//Additional methods omitted for brevity
}
```

The WSDL interface implementation:

```
namespace Project.EFS
{
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://com.tch.cards.service", ConfigurationName = "CardManagementEP")]
    public partial class CardManagementEPClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICardManagementEP>, ICardManagementEP
    {
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSCard> getCardAsync(string clientId, string cardNumber)
        {
            return base.Channel.getCardAsync(clientId, cardNumber);
        }



[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<getPayrollCashHistoryResponse> ICardManagementEP.getPayrollCashHistoryAsync(getPayrollCashHistoryRequest request)
        {
            return base.Channel.getPayrollCashHistoryAsync(request);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<getPayrollCashHistoryResponse> getPayrollCashHistoryAsync(string clientId, string cardNumber, System.DateTime begDate, System.DateTime endDate)
        {
            getPayrollCashHistoryRequest inValue = new getPayrollCashHistoryRequest();
            inValue.clientId = clientId;
            inValue.cardNumber = cardNumber;
            inValue.begDate = begDate;
            inValue.endDate = endDate;
            return ((ICardManagementEP)(this)).getPayrollCashHistoryAsync(inValue);
        }

    //Additional methods omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

The WSDL models:

```
namespace Project.EFS.Models
{
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://com.tch.cards.service/types")]
    public partial class WSCard
    {

        private string cardNumberField;


        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 0)]
        public string cardNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cardNumberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cardNumberField = value;
            }
        }
        //Additional fields, getters, and setters omitted
    }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://com.tch.cards.service/types")]
    public partial class WSCashRecord
    {

        private double amountField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        public double amount
        {
            get
            {
                return this.amountField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.amountField = value;
            }
        }
        //Additional fields, getters, and setters omitted
    }
}

namespace Project.EFS.Methods
{
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "getPayrollCashHistoryResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://com.tch.cards.service", IsWrapped = true)]
    public partial class getPayrollCashHistoryResponse
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("value", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public WSCashRecord[] resultWSCashRecord;

        public getPayrollCashHistoryResponse()
        {
        }

        public getPayrollCashHistoryResponse(WSCashRecord[] result)
        {
            this.resultWSCashRecord = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be blind but I dont see anything in your WSDL etc for getCurrentCashAllAmountsAsync

I see it for getCardAsync and getCashHistoryAsync

Comment: You're not blind, I got mixed up.  Updating now.

Comment: Ok I think that's better.  Thanks for the heads up, this has my head spinning.

Comment: few questions. Who generated the WSDL? and When was it generated? As for which methods work, does the SOAP UI successfully get a response for this call? Also, what my brain is trying to recall for this is. Your simple call, takes in 2 params and that matches the method definition. However, in your WSDL, it actually shows it requires the getPayrollCashHistoryRequest request object, not the 4 params that you are passing in, which in fact is what the public definition shows. Can you step through and validate which getPayrollCashHistoryAsync is called? Its almost like your calling the wrong one.

Comment: I generated the code from a provided URL using svcutil.exe a few weeks ago.  The soap ui does get a good response, and on calls that POST data the data is posted.  The way that it's set up is weird.  There are two getPayrollCashHistoryRequest methods.  One is public and one is not.  The public one is the one that I call, which in turn builds the object and passes it to the non-public method.  I stepped through and confirmed that's what happens.  Why?  I don't know, that's what the WSDL generated.  I guess maybe it's for encapsulation.

Comment: I just stepped through again to confirm, and the object passed to the non-public method looks correct.

Comment: Hmm, if you are correctly calling their API but the result is coming back NULL, I would either try recreating their WSDL just to be sure its correct (in case they made changes), or you need them to validate on their end that the data reached them correctly, so they aren't sending back a null response simply because they goofed. Without them acknowledging the receipt of the data in your call its hard to validate that way. On the way back... you could try doing this with Postman and Fiddler and that would give better details on whats really happening to data going in or coming out.

Comment: Thanks MMEG. They have confirmed that they are getting responses, and using SOAP UI the response is correct. Somehow it’s not getting parsed into the return object correctly.

Comment: @NickBonnell  Does the Soap UI also call the same private version? Check project references side by side and validate they are the same. Use the wsdl the soap ui is using in your .net. Step through both, look at the data generated going outin in both cases, make sure its the same and that the same code path in the wsdl is being used. Do a file compare if you have too on each wsdl. Try the public method and see the result. Check eventlogs etc for weird errors. On their side, they must be doing a query of some sort. They got the data, but could they query and get results?

Comment: Also, did they give you any weird requirements on namespace requirements of your own app? Anything in the SOAP UI web.config that was set that you need to do in your . net APP. By Soap UI are you talking about a WebApp, Xaml or other? Using Fiddler to monitor the calls going out by the Soap UI and your .NET App, you can really see if they are the same incoming / going out. https://www.telerik.com/fiddler Lastly, can you recreate another simple soap ui that works or does it do the same thing when you generate it fresh. If so its probably a config, reference or wsdl issue